# Change Dateformat for nvarchar by sql script

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have to change the datetime format for a given string in a SQL query.
The database is SQL Server 2005, the column is of type `nvarchar(1024)`.

Atm the data is like `2014-05-21`, given the date from today as example.

I should write a script in which I can convert from `2014-05-21` to `21.05.2014`.

What will be the fastest / easiest way to do this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have **dates**, then you ought to store them as `DATETIME` datatype - not as strings!

Comment: why r u taking nvarchar for datetime??

Comment: Not allowed to change, given database with 100.000 data rows

Comment: @user131778 select your column and use replace `-` with `.`...this is faster than convert or some other stuffs if you have your date in the nvarchar format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try as below :-

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) AS [DD.MM.YYYY]
```

For more information :-

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Did this, thank u, not allowed to do so, because the value 0000-00-00 should be converted to 00.00.0000 =/ But it was the right answer, so tahnk u!